# What causes 'The equivalence set for ‘%VARIABLENAME’ cause an invalid extension to COMMON '%BLOCKNAME'

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I am trying to compile and link a Fortran project that includes code written by me as well as code written by some other team. The main program includes a lot of header files where for example common blocks are set up. While compiling the file with the main program, I got plenty of error messages by gfortran stating that `The equivalence set for ‘%VARIABLENAME’ cause an invalid extension to COMMON '%BLOCKNAME'`

The same main program and header files already worked in other programs. I have never seen this message before and could not find any description of what it means. Can anyone tell me more about it?

Comment: Please show us a [mcve].

Comment: We ideally need code to be able to give you an answer to your specific case.  To help you reduce your problem to a [mcve] look for variables that occur in both a common statement and an equivalence statement.

Comment: Expanding slightly on francescalus' comment you've equivalenced something in the common block with something that in memory goes beyond the declared part of the common block, and somehow that is invalid. Without specific examples I can't really say more, save for please move out of the 1960s and code as though it were the 21st century! Both these constructs really belong to a time long, long gone.

Comment: Most compilers in the past haven't checked for this violation and some linkers have provided the additional required space, but it wasn't easy to check this.  Getting to specific compilers, ifort would usually work OK even if you turned off the checking, until you try to compile for threaded parallelism, when you would get a fatal run-time check and have no reasonable way out but to fix the code to comply with the standard.

Comment: @IanBush I know that these constructs belong to a time long, long gone, but I'm working in high energy physics where we have to deal with large program packages written decades ago that very often include common blocks. Even FORTRAN wouldn't be my language of choice for many of the problems I deal with, but I'm supposed to extend existing FORTRAN programs.

Answer (score 0):

I found it out on my own and it was very simple: %VARIABLENAME in the above error message was in fact an array and had a size that was obviously too large (in the order of some millions) for a common block. This was due to the fact that the array dimensionality was set by a parameter in the code I got from another team where they set it to an arbitrary value. Reducing the array size to a value that actually made sense helped immediately.
Take home messages: avoid common blocks, always cross-check the code others give you.